# How can I move specific User to specific channels?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot just for fun with python. I try to move people via command to a specific channel, but it doesn't work. Do someone have a clue how this works? Here my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, user : discord.Member, channelname):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=channelname)
    channel_id = channel.id
    user_id = user.id
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    member = client.get_member(user_id)
    await member.move_to(channel)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong in your code, you're getting a `discord.VoiceChannel` object, and then in `client.get_channel` getting it again, what's the purpose? Same with the user, the argument `user` is already `discord.Member` object, no need getting it again. Here's your fixed code

```py
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, channel_name):
    if member.voice is None:
        # Exiting if the user isn't connected to any voice channel
        return await ctx.send('User must be in a voice channel')

    # Getting the channel
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=channel_name)
    if channel is None:
        return await ctx.send('Invalid channel name')
    
    # Moving the user
    await member.move_to(channel)
```

Also make sure to enable `intents.members` as well as default intents

Comment: Definitely include the checks. You can never assume the user is doing what you expect them to.